# A bag contains one dollar, 50 cents and 25 cents coins in the ratio 5:6:8. If the total amount is 420 dollars, find the total number of coins.

Tags: ratio

I came across this problem and can't seem to figure out the solution.

The options are

789

879

978

798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there are $8A$  25 cents; $6A$ 50 cents; $5A$ dollar. So you will have $$5A + 3A+ 2A=420.$$

Then $A=?$ and the total number of coins is evident.

Comment: What is the number then?

Comment: @LinuxGeek your question looks pretty much like a standard homework assignment, so the least you could do is solve this very easy equation that Paul gave you.

Comment: I did and I get A as 42

Comment: If $A=42$, how many dollar coins are there?

Comment: 42 dollars right

Comment: B. Goddard didnt you see the options?

Comment: @LinuxGeek: No, if $A=42$ there are $5A=210$ dollar coins.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanx I got it ! It was 798.

Comment: @LinuxGeek: It was indeed.